# Unable to create additional database manually in 11g

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration

When I am trying to create a database in Oracle 11g manually, I'm facing below error.

```
SQL> create database test
  2  Datafile '/opt/oradata/test/system01.dbf' size 10M
  3  Sysaux datafile '/opt/oradata/test/sysaux01.dbf' size 10M
  4  Logfile '/opt/oradata/test/redo01.log' size 10M,
  5  '/opt/oradata/test/redo02.log' size 10M
  6  Undo tablespace undotbs1
  7  Datafile '/opt/oradata/test/undo01.dbf' size 10M
  8  Default temporary tablespace temp
  9  Tempfile '/opt/oradata/test/temp01.dbf' size 10M;

Error:

SQL> /
create database test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
ORA-01519: error while processing file '?/rdbms/admin/doptim.bsq' near line 15
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SYSTEM
Process ID: 4562
Session ID: 1 Serial number: 3
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Do you really think 10M is enough space for each of those tablespaces? How did you pick those sizes? The 'unable to create extent' message means it ran out of storage space, because SYSTEM is too small. (As are the others, that's just the first one it failed on). Maybe you'd have more luck using DBCA. [Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/create.htm). Database creation is off-topic for this site anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SYSTEM"

If you look at this error it clearly says it's not able to create the initial extent since the size of the extent required is more than the file size. So, it leaves you with the two options

1) create DMT tablespace.

2) Increase the file size (100M rather than 10M).

Thank You,

Sid